# String to SecByteBlock Conversion Issues

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I'm having an issue with allocating a new key for 3 key Triple DES in crypto++.

I've generated a new key as a string but need to allocate it to SecByteBlock for use in Crypto++.

Currently I generate a random key using the PRNG at the start, but when I attempt to change the key using string output from DES_EDE3, it appears to use the same key.

I think the issue is with the conversion between string and SecByteBlock, or the allocation to SecByteBlock as shown below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SecByteBlock GENERATOR::setKey(string keyString){

    SecByteBlock replacementKey(24);

    replacementKey= SecByteBlock(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(keyString.data()), keyString.size());
    return newKey = replacementKey;
}
```

Comment: What is the type and lifetime of `newkey`? - you don't declare it in the above code.  Why do you believe this is not working?

Comment: What is "SecByteBlock"? What is "newKey"? Too many missing details.

Comment: newKey is a private SecBlockByte in the object GENERATOR. I'm unsure what you mean by lifetime? It appears to not be working because on the same input for DES_EDE3, when the key has supposedly changed the output remains the same. SecBlockByte is a variable type defined in Crypto++ I believe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I attempt to change the key using string output from DES_EDE3, it appears to use the same key

It almost sounds like you are trying to use 3-DES as a PRF keyed with a password. If so, use [HKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/hkdf_8h_source.html). Its designed for these types of expand-then extract operations.

HKDF is available in Crypto++ 5.6.3 and above. If you need it for a downlevel client, then copy the header where you need it.

---

```
SecByteBlock GENERATOR::setKey(string keyString){

    SecByteBlock replacementKey(24);

    replacementKey= SecByteBlock(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(keyString.data()), keyString.size());
    return newKey = replacementKey;
}
```

Though you size `replacementKey` to 24, it could be resized by the assignment `replacementKey= SecByteBlock(...)`.

You might want to try the following:

```
SecByteBlock GENERATOR::setKey(const string& keyString)
{    
    SecByteBlock key((const byte*)keyString.data(), keyString.size());

    if(key,size() < DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH)
        key.CleanGrow(DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH);
    else
        key.resize(DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH);

    return key;
}
```

[`CleanGrow`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html#l00662) sizes the memory block to `DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH` and backfills the block with 0's as needed. [`resize`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/secblock_8h_source.html#l00679) will truncate to `DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH` if its too large.

You could also do something like:

```
SecByteBlock key(DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH);
size_t s = STDMIN(key.size(), keyString.size());

memcpy(key.data(), keyString.data(), s);
if(s < DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH)
    memset(key.data()+s, 0, DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH-s);
```

### -----

To combine the first two, you might consider this:

```
SecByteBlock GENERATOR::setKey(const string& keyString)
{
    // Block is unintialized
    SecByteBlock key(DES_EDE3::KEYLENGTH);

    HKDF<SHA256> kdf;
    kdf.Derivekey(key.data(), key.size(), (const byte*)keyString.data(), keyString.size(), NULL, 0);

    return key;
}
```

### -----

You can output a `SecByteBlock` with code like:

```
SecByteBlock b = GENERATOR::setKey(...);
...

cout << "Derived key: "
ArraySource as(b.data(), b.size(), true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(cout)));
cout << endl;
```

The following with encode it using Base64:

```
ArraySource as(b.data(), b.size(), true, new Base64Encoder(new FileSink(cout)));
```